# How can I use string interpolation in a pug template's image tag - src attr?

Tags: javascript, pug, templating, string-interpolation

How can I use my `var imgsrc` inside the `img(src="")`?

```
- var imgsrc =  '../assets/images/tasting-notes-ingredients/'
img(src="#{imgsrc}grapes.png")
```

Comment: `img(src = imgsrc + "grapes.png");` ? Using `+` to concat the string

Comment: https://mobile.twitter.com/wesbos/status/742800759432085504 I saw this but doesnt look excatly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter link you posted is for inline *HTML element* declaration. You want to concatenate a variable with a string, which you can do like this:

```
- var imgsrc =  "../assets/images/tasting-notes-ingredients/"
img(src= imgsrc + "grapes.png")
```

Doesn't matter what the order is, and you can also set the `src` parameter to be equal to only the variable if you need. You can concatenate the variable & `grapes.png` earlier, and just set `src` to be equal to only the variable.

```
- var imgsrc =  "../assets/images/tasting-notes-ingredients/"
- imgsrc     += "grapes.png"
img(src= imgsrc)
```